# Synchronized Editing of Plain Text Across Two Java Applications

Tags: java, networking, text, synchronization

Ok, I have been researching how to do this over the past few days and I haven't really come any closer to finding a solution or example. Basically, I have a server/client system set up so that I can send and receive text between two Java applications. I just can't figure out how to go about keeping the text in sync with each other. (Something like Google Docs)

If anyone can point me in the right direction or show/link me an example it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute force way would be to just send the entire text blob whenever it's updated, and let the other side sync up to it.

There are two main problems with this approach:

1. If the text blob is really really big then there's redundant data being sent back and forth
2. There can be merge problems if many concurrent changes are being made on both sides, especially if they are editing the exact same area of the text

The second problem could be mitigated by having some sort of acknowledge reply so you'd know if the updated blob was "accepted" on the other side.  This way, both sides can maintain "agreement" on what is the valid state of the data.  However, this could still break down if neither side will acknowledge each other's changes (for whatever reason).

The only other general idea I can think of would be to leverage some library that is used by version control systems, like SVN or GIT.  These might have nice diff and merge features that could make updating easier.  Sending only diffs would also mitigate problem #1 above.